# Unexpected results from an sql query which uses RIGHT JOIN

Tags: sql, join

I have an sql query which seems to return an unexpected blank row. This query has an right join to another table but when return the rows it returns me a null value..

```
  SELECT e.error_id, e.user_id, e.error_title, e.error_content, e.error_answers, 
         e.error_votes, e.error_views, e.error_added_date, u.user_name
  FROM errors e
  JOIN users u
    ON u.user_id=e.user_id
  RIGHT JOIN answers a
    ON a.error_id=e.error_id AND a.answer_accepted='1'
  GROUP BY e.error_id
  ORDER BY e.error_added_date DESC
```

This query should return me one single row but It returns me the expected row and one row with blank values.. Why is that?

**Entries**

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
answer_id | error_id | user_id | answer_content | answer_accepted | answer_votes | answer_added_date |
1         | 3        | 1       | text           | 0               | 0            | 2013-01-31 12:49:12
2         | 3        | 1       | text           | 1               | 1            | 2013-01-31 12:52:29
3         | 3        | 1       | text           | 0               |-1            | 2013-01-31 12:53:45
4         | 2        | 1       | text           | 0               |-1            | 2013-01-31 12:53:45
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Results:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   1 | 1    | text |  3   | 0    |  2   |  2013-01-29 16:56:20  |  Mihai Matei |
|NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |       NULL            |  NULL        |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you show the results?

Comment: I'm wondering if there are any answers with a null error id.  Since you're grouping on error_id, it might get a blank row from that.

Comment: I've just posted the results.. thank you

Comment: Can you post some sample data?  Don't see anything that would be causing this.  Personally prefer LEFT JOINs though -- think they read cleaner.

Comment: I've just added.. This should return me the 4th row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are doing a Right Join. I think you want a Left Join or an Inner Join.

A right join means return all the table rows on the right and the matching rows from the left. Because your result set doesn't include any columns from the answers table (the right table), you can get a set of all nulls. In other words, there is a row in the answers table with no corresponding rows in the error and users table.

Given the additional criteria in the comment on this answer, here's the query I would try:

```
  SELECT e.error_id, e.user_id, e.error_title, e.error_content, e.error_answers, 
         e.error_votes, e.error_views, e.error_added_date, u.user_name
  FROM errors e
  JOIN users u
    ON u.user_id=e.user_id
  LEFT JOIN answers a
    ON a.error_id = e.error_id and a.answer_accepted = '1'
  WHERE a.answer_id is null
  GROUP BY e.error_id
  ORDER BY e.error_added_date DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. Than tell me please how should I make this query to return me only the errors which doesn't have any answer with answer_accepted='1' in asnwers table

Comment: Thank you again.. I found the solution using `WHERE e.error_id NOT IN (
             SELECT DISTINCT error_id FROM answers WHERE answer_accept='1'  
           )`

Comment: See my answer above for a query to try.

Comment: I would recommend the Left join with the null check over the Not In. Negative conditions (like NOT IN) tend to have poor performance.

Comment: This works! Thank you! I didn't thought about this method.. good to know :) (I've change something on your query because something was wrong)